# Why do we use super in ruby when I can inherit without its use?

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, initialization, super

I have searched on here for an answer to this question and couldn't find what I was after (in exact terms) so I'm gonna be slightly greedy and ask for some of the communities time. I hope to make my question as applicable as possible.

So, some context, I've been struggling with the idea of classes, class variables and methods for the last week but over the last 2 days have made serious headways in my understanding. However now I am faced with inheritance and can't work out why super would be used when I can just inherit without using it.

For example:

```
class Animal 
   def initialize (type, breed, age)
     @type = type
     @breed = breed
     @age = age
   end
end

class Dog < Animal
end

class Cat < Animal
end

class Fish 
end

woof = Dog.new("dog", "shitzu", 12)
meow = Cat.new("cat", "tabby", 5)
fish = Fish.new("fish", "gold", 2)

Output:

=> #<Dog:0x00000001447680 @type="dog", @breed="shitzu", @age=12> 
=> #<Cat:0x0000000140c918 @type="cat", @breed="tabby", @age=5> 
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0)
```

As you can see, I have been able to inherit from Animal on both my Dog and Cat classes, which I marked for inheritance, but on my Fish I have not been able to, because I didn't inherit.

If someone could explain why we use super, and point out flaws in my understanding, I'd be very grateful, I understand that I may be completely just misunderstanding usage here, but I'd like to just get it clarified. Thanks for your time, appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you wondering about explicit calls to `super`? (like, when a method calls 'super' to run its parent classes' version of the method?)

Comment: If you wanted to customize the `initialize` method in class `Dog`, simply inheriting from class `Animal` wouldn't let you customize it. If in class `Dog`, you did something like `def initialize(type, breed, age, color)` and then had `super(type, breed, age)` and `@color = color`, this would allow you to change up the initialize method you inherited while `super` calls on its parent class `Animal` to initialize the other instance variables you had

Comment: Did you mean to use `super` in the example? I don't understand how the question is related to the code example.

Comment: @gmcnaughton  and philip yoo (sorry i cant tag both in same comment) explained it. sorry for the silly question, I have just been doing a few different online courses and it seems to get added in here and there but I couldnt tell when it was supposed to be used

Comment: @JoshuaCheek well that's half my question, to be fair I don't know, I'm kinda asking how super is meant to be applied, I thought it tied into the initialize method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `super` lets a class override a method that it inherits from its parent and customize it.

For instance, in your example, `Dog` and `Cat` inherit `#initialize` from `Animal` - but what if we wanted some special logic for `Dog`?

```
class Dog < Animal
  def initialize(type, breed, age)
    raise "Sorry, dogs don't live that long!" if age > 100

    # Everything looks good - let Animal#initialize run now
    super
  end
end
```

This lets `Dog` customize what its initialize method does, but still call through to the original inherited method.

Comment: Yes. In short it's where your subclass has methods "almost but not quite" like their parent class.

Comment: So we basically use super to add in extra features whilst also inheriting the exisiting parent features?

Comment: _"Using super lets a class override a method that it inherits from its parent"_ is misleading. A class can override a method defined in its Parent class by simply defining it without `super`.  `super` calls the original method from the parent class.

Comment: @JohnVonNeumann yep, spot on! (it's not just for #initialize either, the same technique works for any method you want to override).

Comment: There's something very subtle in this example that the op should be aware of; the values provided in the parameter list are implicitly being passed through to the call to `super`.  In some circumstances, values will need to be explicitly passed to the `super` method.

Answer (score 0):

> Excerpted from [Inheritance - What is inherited?](https://web.archive.org/web/20171006215548/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/625/inheritance/14883/what-is-inherited#t=20171006215548229306). The original author was [nus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115652/nus). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/14883). The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 625 and example ID: 14883.

**Methods are inherited**

```
class A
  def boo; p 'boo' end
end

class B < A; end

b = B.new
b.boo # => 'boo'
```

**Class methods are inherited**

```
class A
  def self.boo; p 'boo' end
end

class B < A; end

p B.boo # => 'boo'
```

**Constants are inherited**

```
class A
  WOO = 1
end

class B < A; end

p B::WOO # => 1
```

But beware, they can be overridden:

```
class B
  WOO = WOO + 1
end

p B::WOO # => 2
```

**Instance variables are inherited:**

```
class A
  attr_accessor :ho
  def initialize
    @ho = 'haha'
  end
end

class B < A; end

b = B.new
p b.ho # => 'haha'
```

Beware, if you override the methods that initialize instance variables without calling `super`, they will be nil. Continuing from above:

```
class C < A
  def initialize; end
 end

c = C.new
p c.ho    # => nil
```

**Class instance variables are not inherited:**

```
class A
    @foo = 'foo'
    class << self
        attr_accessor :foo
    end
end

class B < A; end

p B.foo # => nil

# The accessor is inherited, since it is a class method
#
B.foo = 'fob' # possible
```

**Class variables aren't really inherited**

They are shared between the base class and all subclasses as 1 variable:

```
class A
    @@foo = 0
    def initialize
        @@foo  += 1 
        p @@foo
    end
end

class B < A;end

a = A.new # => 1
b = B.new # => 2
```

So continuing from above:

```
class C < A
  def initialize
    @@foo = -10
    p @@foo
  end
end

a = C.new # => -10
b = B.new # => -9
```